# Android PreferenceActivity and dialog fragments

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, preferenceactivity

The app I am developing has an activity that extends `SherlockFragmentActivity`. I would like to use the preferences api in order to easily add preferences to the activity. Since I would like to support api level 8 and above, I have to extend the activity from the class `SherlockPreferenceActivity`.

The problem is that the activity needs to show a dialog. The dialog extends `SherlockDialogFragment`. The `show()` method of the dialog needs two parameters: a `FragmentManager` object and a `String` tag. 
In order to get the `FragmentManager` object, i used to call the `getSupportFragmentManager()` method of the activity. This method is missing from `SherlockPreferenceActivity`. I tried to use `getFragmentManager()` but Eclipse says that

> The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is
>   not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)

How can I show the dialog fragment from `SherlockPreferenceActivity`?

Comment: I have the same problem. We need to obtain the FragmentManager from the support package but there is no such thing in the SherlockPreferenceActivity. =(

Comment: I have solved it in another way. Create another activity under the same packege (remember to add this new activity to the manifest). Extend SherlockPreferenceActivity and implement the interface SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener. Look at the android developer site in order to understand how to write this activity. Use this activity to manage user preferences. From the other activity, when the user press the setting button, start the preference activity with an intent. From the main activity you will able to read the settings using the PreferenceManager.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Shared Preferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) rather than using the `PreferenceActivity`. Declare these references in a separate helper class rather than extending it to an Activity.This gives you the flexibility of creating a custom layout.

**Example:**

```
public class SharePrefManager {
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
    Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "selfhelppref";

    //Your configurable fields
    public static final String KEY_PREF1 = "pref1";
    public static final String KEY_PREF2 = "pref2";
    public static final String KEY_PREF3 = "pref3";


    public SharePrefManager(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    //Setter function for configurable field
    public void setPref(String key, String value){
       editor.putString(key, value);
    }

   //Getter function for configurable field
   public String getPref(String key){
           return editor.getString(key);
   }
}
```

**Referencing on your activity**

```
SharePrefManager SM = new SharePrefManager(this);
SM.setPref(SM.KEY_PREF1, "name");
String value = SM.getPref(SM.KEY_PREF1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SherlockDialogFragment.getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Example:
`mySherlockDialogFragment.show(mySherlockDialogFragment.getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "my_tag");`